# What does "The constructor FastDateFormat(String, TimeZone, Locale) is not visible" mean?

Tags: java, date, factory, apache-commons

SimpleDateFormat lets me do this:

```
SimpleDateFormat mySimpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

But FastDateFormat doesn't:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat;
//...
FastDateFormat myFastDateFormatter = new FastDateFormat(str, tz, loc);
```

Now it complains that:

> "The constructor FastDateFormat(String, TimeZone, Locale) is not visible"

The error message doesn't lead me anywhere... What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike, Java's `SimpleDateFormat`, you cannot simply declare an instance of Apache's `FastDateFormat` class.

Instead, `FastDateFormat` statically serves up instances of the class via the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) - you must call the class' static method `getInstance`, as in the following:

```
String dateFormatPattern = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
FastDateFormat myFastDateFormatter = FastDateFormat.getInstance(dateFormatPattern);
```

Now you have a myFastDateFormatter loaded configured with that date format pattern.

You can use it to parse strings into real Dates, assuming those strings conform to your dateFormatPattern:

```
String dateString = "2014-04-03T14:02:57.182+0200";
Date myDate = myFastDateFormatter.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Thank you, past me. I had to refer to this today after FindBugs complained about a non-threadsafe usage of SimpleDateFormatter.